# how to add file seperator into javax.servlet.http.Part.getSubmittedFileName

Tags: java, servlet-3.0

I'm using File Upload API in my project. I want to get file path into html input file for delete the uploaded file after uploading.

```
<input type="file" id="document" name="document">
```

I wrote this code in my servlet

```
final Part filePart = request.getPart("document");
System.out.println(filePart.getSubmittedFileName());
```

it gives me this result

```
C:Usersftk1187Desktopdadwd.pdf
```

I want to add file seperator in this result but I don't know how so can anyone give me a suggestion?

Comment: You won't be able to re-insert the file separator at the original positions because that information is simply lost. An assumption of mine: the submitted file name shouldn't contain the whole filepath at which the file was located on the client but only the filename. Seems like a strange behaviour of your client. So I personally won't rely on that behaviour.

Comment: @grubi OK, I understand. I have one more question. I tried to get <input type="file" id="document" name="document"> value with String[] values=request.getParameterValues("document"); but it gave me nullpointerexception. Why I can't get values this method? Also I want to explain why I want to do this. I want to delete uploaded file from client side after upload completed.

Comment: I'm not that deep inside the file upload api of the servlet spec, but most probably the uploaded file is simply not available as a paramter value. HTML forms with file uploads normally use the multipart encoding type which makes each file a separate part in the request body (that's why you used `request.getPart(...)`). But that doesn't matter, because you can't delete the file on the client from within the server. The server has no access to the filesystem of your client (unless the server runs on the client. But that would be somewhat pointless).